# Typescript reduce return wrong Type and also forbid to assert it

Tags: typescript, types, return, assertion

Faced very strange ts behaviour.

```typescript
type Labels = Record<string, boolean | undefined>

type LabelGroups = Record<string, Labels>

export function reduceLabelGroups(labelGroups: LabelGroups) {
    const labels = Object.entries(labelGroups).reduce((valueMap, [, value]) => ({...valueMap, ...value}), {});

    return labels;
}
```

It should return Labels Type after reduce - but it returns just {}
If you try to assert Labels like a

(...{} as Labels);

it throws error "Unnecessary cast: Array#reduce accepts a type parameter for the default value."
How can I return type without any "as unknown as Labels" after return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just as the error says - `.reduce` accepts a type parameter, so use it.

```
export function reduceLabelGroups(labelGroups: LabelGroups) {
    return Object.entries(labelGroups).reduce<Labels>((valueMap, [, value]) => ({...valueMap, ...value}), {});
}
```

Might be more appropriate to use `Object.values`, since you're not using the keys.

```
export function reduceLabelGroups(labelGroups: LabelGroups) {
    return Object.values(labelGroups).reduce<Labels>((valueMap, value) => ({...valueMap, ...value}), {});
}
```

Or perhaps avoid `.reduce` entirely, it's [not so appropriate here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qaGjS7-qWzg)

```
export function reduceLabelGroups(labelGroups: LabelGroups) {
    const valueMap: Labels = {};
    for (const value of Object.values(labelGroups)) {
        Object.assign(valueMap, value);
    }
    return valueMap;
};
```

You can do shorter, but it requires a type assertion.

```
export function reduceLabelGroups(labelGroups: LabelGroups) {
    return Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(labelGroups)) as Labels;
};
```